# ClassNotFoundException results in no classes getting loaded

Tags: java, classpath

I am stuck on a problem because I am not very good in Java. Could you help me.

**PLEASE NOTE: It is not a duplicate as the classpaths are specified and I have already gone through the "duplicate question".**

Could you please point me in the right direction?

My code compiles fine and all the compiled files, along with original files, **are stored on Desktop.**

**ERROR**

```
Desktop beeeeaasssst$ java com.StudentDemo
Error: Could not find or load main class com.StudentDemo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.StudentDemo
```

**CODE**

```
    package com;

public class StudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student one = new Student(1,"Ravi",45);
        Student two = new Student(2,"Amit",65);
        Student three = new Student(3,"pooka",55);

        System.out.println("Student with highest marks is " + compareStudents(one,two,three));
    }

    public static String compareStudents (Student one, Student two, Student three) {
        Student st = one;

        if (two.getMarks() > st.getMarks())
            st=two;

        if (three.getMarks() > st.getMarks())
            st=three;

        return st.getName();
    }
}

class Student {
    private int rollNo;
    private String name;
    private double marks;

    public Student (int rollNo, String name, double marks) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public double getMarks(){
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(double marks){
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

The code compiles and generates 2 different class files but I cannot run the program. I tried 2 ways from my terminal:

```
java com.StudentDemo . (Since package used is com).
```

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

1. The source file should be in `com/StudentDemo.java` relative to the directory you're in.
2. Compile with `javac com/StudentDemo.java`.
3. Execute with `java com.StudentDemo`.

Most of this is clearly stated in the accepted answer to the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean).

Comment: I did put the StudentDemo.java in a folder "com" on the desktop. My pwd is desktop as well but when I compile using javac com/StudentDemo.java then I get javac: file not found: com/StudentDemo.java

Comment: So you didn't put it there, or you weren't in that directory.

Comment: when you say I wasnt in that directory, do you mean my pwd needs to be 'desktop' or should it be 'desktop/com' ? The latter would defeat the purpose of making a folder 'com'.  I was able to compile the file from desktop but not run it. Why is there this discrepency? I checked the files are all in places like you said. Executing  gives the same error as before "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: Your *cwd* needs to be 'desktop', the folder containing `com`, as per (1) above. By 'that directory' I meant the one you claimed you were in. The compiler doesn't lie. Examine your assumptions. Try `ls -l com` for example. Are you using *exactly* the `javac` command line above? Or are there other options?

Comment: This is so weird. I did everything you said and still managed to screw it up. I ll keep working but I think I have exhausted my brain.

Comment: point to be noted : When I remove the line 'pacakge com;', then the program starts working. How does 'package com;' relate with folder 'com' ?

Comment: Well, how do you think it relates? Do you think it's just a coincidence? It isn't. And if you removed the package statement you would also have had to adjust both commands, and you haven't stated how. Please provide the result of `ls -l com`.

Comment: I understand that during compilation the program is supposed to generate a 'com' folder but it isn't doing so (i guess). The result is :Desktop beeeeaasssst$ ls -l com
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 beeeeaasssst  staff   623 21 Jan 20:01 Student.class                           
-rw-r--r--  1 beeeeaasssst  staff  1349 21 Jan 20:01 StudentDemo.class
-rw-r--r--@ 1 beeeeaasssst  staff   966 21 Jan 19:18 StudentDemo.java

Comment: Eh? If a`com` directory isn't being generated what is the meaning of all your prior claims that it exists? And how do you explain the `ls -l com` output? Of course it is being generated. You aren't making sense.

Comment: I had to make it manually and put the compiled filed in it later. If I run the program from desktop it doesnt generate 'desktop/com', and futhermore, doesnt put the compiled files in there. I hope that clarifies what I meant when I say 'com' isnt getting generated.

Comment: Running the program doesn't generate directories. Compiling it might, if they don't already exist. According to your last comment under the deleted answer you don't have `com/StudentDemo.java` at all. You need to carry out steps 1-4 above exactly as specified and it will work. All the evidence is that you haven't done so, and all you're doing here is making contradictory statements.

Comment: I meant compiling, not running.** pwd for all the steps is desktop**. Step 1) I have a folder 'com' (that I made) and I put StudentDemo.java inside it. Step 2) I compiled it and that works. The 2 generated classes are now inside com along with original file (StudentDemo.java). Step 3) Throws error: Error: Could not find or load main class com.StudentDemo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.StudentDemo

Comment: I have more info. I wrote a hello world program on my desktop in the most simplest form. But it still gives me the same exception. Is something wrong with my computer?